# How does the C compiler interpret the following code sequence

Tags: c, parsing

I have this C code line:

```
int a;
a = (1, 2, 3);

printf("%d", a);
```

Why the value `3` is printed? (the last one).

Comment: I believe Google is not down currently – why don't you consult it for some beginners' tutorials or language references in which operators are explained?

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate newbie question.

Comment: see [What does the comma operator `,` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/1708801)

Comment: @JohannGerell To wonder, yes. To ask here without any sort of basic searching, no. That's pretty much the main thing given as a valid reason for down voting.

Comment: @hvd I doubt that many newbies can successfully formulate a Google search term for that unless they already know that ',' (comma) is an _operator_ in C, and if they did know that, the need to ask at all would diminish. Or how would _you_ do that search?

Comment: @JohannGerell I would search for "what does a comma-separated list of numbers mean in c". And that does give an answered question in its results. Actually, the question you find in the results was answered by me, but I promise I didn't go through my own posting history to guess search terms that might work. :)

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator evaluates all its "members" but returns the value of the last expression.
From the C11 standard:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
>   of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; **the result
>   has its type and value.**

Comment: Why is this thing legal in C? Is there any useful need for this fancy syntax?

Comment: @MariusMarusanici [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c).